# Vpn Client to connect to Windows 7 VPN

Tags: vpn

I am looking for a third party VPN client that I can use to connect to my home VPN which is setup through Windows 7. I don't want to use built in Android VPN. Many of the VPN clients I've seen on the market solely connect to their own vpns and I haven't seen one that allows for you to enter custom address and information. I have a rooted Verizon Galaxy Nexus running 4.0.2 with the stock ROM.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `5 VPN` app in ICS?